# help with the edit box/Input Box

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a simple dialog with a label and edit box, then created a class, CInputDlg, added member variables for the label and edit box, and  called it

```
CInputDlg dialog
dialog.m_label = TEXT("Enter a number:");
if (dialog.DoModal() == IDOK) {
  // Do something
}
```

Now how do I display the text which is entered into the edit box?

Comment: I just want to enter numeric values and strings so how can i get them in a double or string variable and display in afxmessgaebox...!!

Answer (score 0):

Try WM_GETTEXT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632627(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: When i type in TextBox. the wizard does not shows up and included the file showed in WM_GETTEXT in define now what to do..??

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using and what version of .Net ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Handler for the OK button on the Dialog, you should get the TextBox.GetText(), and put it back into a public CString member m_InputString.  Then, from the calling function, you can read dialog.m_InputString.